# Excel removing valid formula inserted by Python

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, xlsx, openpyxl

I am trying to generate an excel xlsx report in Python, using **openpyxl**, but there is a problem. **Excel keeps removing formula from my sheet** in a few specific cells.

I printed what is being inserted and it seems absolutely valid, if I paste it from console to the cell it shows the exact result. I even tried to insert the formula without the leading '=' and it did so, when I opened it in excel and added '=' it worked.

This is the given formula, just a SUM of cells on a condition of some other value in matching rows:

**=SUMIF($C$27:$C$243;A249;$I$27:$I$243)**

The error on opening workbook is as follows:

[image]
[image]

When I do not insert anything in that particular cell everything opens smooth, no warnings. When I insert it manually, however, **excel shows warning** saying that the cell with formula is not protected. Not sure if that should be in any way an issue.
I cannot quite wrap my head around it. Excel error log is as useful as ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please pay attention to the warning in the documentation: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html#using-formulae

> NB you must use the English name for a function and function arguments must be separated by commas and not other punctuation such as semi-colons.

Comment: Wow... 
Thank you a lot, I totally missed that. 
Fun thing is, when I open the resulting excel, there are semicolons, even though Python is inserting commas now.

You are a lifesaver. Or timesaver, at least. Thank you.

Comment: MS thought it would be fun to localise things like formulae and macros. You can change the decimal separator but only on a global basis. :-/

Comment: Like it wasn't bad enough that US and EU need different decimal separators.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I had this issue with a node excel library and it was the same issue (; instead of ,)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below syntax to update a formula in excel, or make use to use r in front of string, it avoids you to have backslashes in the formula

I tested that out, works perfectly fine:

```
formula = r'=CONCATENATE($N$2,"=",N3,";", $O$2,"=",O3,";", $P$2,"=",P3,";", $Q$2,"=",Q3,";", $R$2,"=",R3,";",$S$2,"=",S3,";",$T$2,"=",T3,";", $U$2,"=",U3,";")'

test_case_sheet.cell(row=row_index, column=header_col_map_dict['TestDataKey']).value = formula
```