# Running functions from excel add-ins in Python using openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I would like to know whether, or not, is possible to call Excel functions which are installed from an add-ins, with openpyxl.

For example, I have no problem as long as I use native Excel functions.

```
# Load libraries
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

# Creates Excel workbook
wb = Workbook()
wb.save("Example.xlsx")

# Excel writer definition
book = load_workbook("Example.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Example.xlsx", engine = "openpyxl")
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
ws = book.active

# Cell value definition
ws["A1"] = 1
ws["A2"] = 2
ws["A3"] = 3

# Native Excel function applied "SUM()"
ws["D4"] = "=SUM(A1:A3)"

# Saving workbook
writer.save()
```

However, I cannot do the same when I try to use a function which is installed from an add-in.

Let's say I have installed next add-in:

http://www.xlxtrfun.com/XlXtrFun/XlXtrFun.htm

And I would like to use the "INTERPOLATE" function.

```
# Load libraries
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import pandas as pd

# Creates Excel workbook
wb = Workbook()
wb.save("Example.xlsx")

# Excel writer definition
book = load_workbook("Example.xlsx")
writer = pd.ExcelWriter("Example.xlsx", engine = "openpyxl")
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
ws = book.active

# Cell value definition
ws["A1"] = 1
ws["A2"] = 2
ws["A3"] = 3
ws["A4"] = 4
ws["A5"] = 5 

ws["B1"] = -0.1
ws["B2"] = 0.32
ws["B3"] = 0.62
ws["B4"] = -0.49
ws["B5"] = 0.72

ws["A7"] = 1.5

# Add-in function applied "INTERPOLATE()"
ws["B7"] = "=Interpolate($A$1:$A$5;$B$1:$B$5;A7;1;0)"

# Saving workbook
writer.save()
```

Code works perfectly. However, as soon as I open Example.xlsx I have next message:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/54f1vbf8hexkktu/Screenshot_3.PNG?dl=0&m=

and this is the result:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/54f1vbf8hexkktu/Screenshot_3.PNG?dl=0&m=

As you can be seen, there is no value in cell "B7".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Err:508 in formula written with Openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56970851/err508-in-formula-written-with-openpyxl) or this [excel-removing-valid-formula-inserted-by-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46522917/excel-removing-valid-formula-inserted-by-python)

Comment: Thank you very much for your info @stovfl! It is working perfectly!

Comment: I suspect some add-in formulae might also require their own XML namespaces though that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Thanks @CharlieClark  for your comment!